# Is there a way to use the native Windows 8.1 alarm app on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1

The native Windows 10 Alarms app looks quite ugly and I would love to keep the look of the Windows 8.1 app. I have access to the directory because I have removed TrustedInstaller's authority. So, I can mess with the files if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. Searching the [Microsoft store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-bd/p/windows-alarms-clock/9wzdncrfj3pr?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:regionofsystemrequirementstab) only shows the Windows 10 (Requires 17134.0 or higher) version of the Alarms and Clock UWP App. There is no version for the Windows 8 or 8.1 app. And messing with files in WindowsApps folder won't be good.